# Add the top and bottom ticks to the y-axis in multiple y axes figure produced by 'pgfplots'?

Tags: pgfplots

It is common to draw multiple y axes figure, but sometimes there are not the top and bottom ticks in the outer y axes produce by **pgfplot**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{
        scale only axis,
        enlargelimits=false,
        width=0.4\textwidth,
        height=2cm,
        xmin=0.5,
        xmax=16.5,
        xticklabel=\empty,
        xtick={1,2,...,16},
        leftinnery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style=green!75!black,
            ytick style=green!75!black,
            ylabel=a,
            ylabel style=green!75!black,
            axis y line*=left,
            y axis line style=green!75!black,
            },
        rightinnery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style=blue,
            ytick style=blue,
            ylabel=b,
            ylabel style=blue,
            axis y line*=right,
            y axis line style=blue,
            },
        leftoutery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            ytick style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            ylabel=c,
            ylabel style=red,
            axis y line*=left,
            y axis line style={red,xshift=-1.7cm},
            },
        rightoutery/.style={
            every y tick label/.append style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            ytick style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            ylabel=d,
            ylabel style=brown,
            axis y line*=right,
            y axis line style={brown,xshift=1.4cm},
            },
        }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[leftinnery]
                \addplot[green!75!black, mark=o, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   10
                    };
                \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {东湖};
            \end{axis}            
            \begin{axis}[rightinnery]
                \addplot[blue, mark=x, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    2   1.6
                    3   2
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[leftoutery]
                \addplot[red, mark=+, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    3   2
                    };
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[rightoutery]
                \addplot[brown, mark=Mercedes star, draw] table[x index=0]{
                    1   3
                    };
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can make it to

[image]

Sometimes many figures need to changed to add those ticks, so it is a way to add it automatically? If those can be add, how to omit the tick labels to the bottom and the top tick in order to arrange the two figures in the vertical direction without overlapping of labels.

Comment: You can add `extra y ticks` using `axis cs:` values, or just draw fake tick marks using `axis rel cs:`